# SP 2010: Set RSS settings for a web application with powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, development

PowerShell allows to set/retrieve web application settings e.g.

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $siteURL 
$webApp.DefaultTimeZone

Will return the Default Time Zone of the web application. 
I'm now looking for the RSS parameter for a web application.

RSS Settings
Specify the server-wide settings for RSS feeds.  Enable RSS feeds: YES / NO

Not sure if this is possible to retrieve since it's not even listed:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [SPWebApplication.SyndicationEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.syndicationenabled)

```
$webApp.SyndicationEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebAppplication -Identity http://webapp
$webapp.SyndicationEnabled
$webapp.update()
```